# Cloud Run and Prestashop infinite index.php redirect

Tags: apache2, prestashop, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to execute Prestashop 1.8.2 on Cloud Run and Apache2 (PHP 8.1). I installed Prestashop locally. After this, I transfered the writable folder of Prestashop ("var/cache" "var/logs" "img" "mails" "modules" "translations" "upload" "download" "override" "app/config" "app/Resources/translations") on a File Shares on Azure (I didn't find a working solution on GCP, I tried Gfuse and Cloud Storage and Filestore is too expensive for the 1 TB minimun size requirement). These Fileshares are mounted with a script on startup of container. When I call the Cloud Run endpoint, the service return "Service Unavailable". On the logs, the error is "The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error.".
On the Apache logs, the error is the following:

[Wed Jan 17 13:34:31.489141 2024] [core:error] [pid 144] [client 169.254.169.126:39609] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://prestashop-prod-4fbtvz3dva-ew.a.run.app/
[Wed Jan 17 13:34:31.520628 2024] [mpm_prefork:debug] [pid 141] prefork.c(970): AH00165: Accept mutex: none (default: pthread)
[Wed Jan 17 13:34:31.542276 2024] [core:debug] [pid 144] core.c(3956): [client 169.254.169.126:39609] AH00121: r->uri = /htdocs/prestashop-prod-1.8.2/index.php, referer: https://prestashop-prod-4fbtvz3dva-ew.a.run.app/
[Wed Jan 17 13:34:31.577024 2024] [core:debug] [pid 144] core.c(3962): [client 169.254.169.126:39609] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /htdocs/prestashop-prod-1.8.2/index.php, referer: https://prestashop-prod-4fbtvz3dva-ew.a.run.app/
[Wed Jan 17 13:34:31.592794 2024] [core:debug] [pid 144] core.c(3962): [client 169.254.169.126:39609] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /htdocs/prestashop-prod-1.8.2/index.php, referer: https://prestashop-prod-4fbtvz3dva-ew.a.run.app/
...
[Wed Jan 17 13:34:31.723208 2024] [core:debug] [pid 144] core.c(3962): [client 169.254.169.126:39609] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /favicon.ico, referer: https://prestashop-prod-4fbtvz3dva-ew.a.run.app/

Then, it seems that the issue is a infinite index.php loop.

I performed the following checks:

- Volumes are writable
- /var/www/html files are readable and owned by www-data
- I enabled SSL on Prestashop DB manually with the domain of Cloud Run (prestashop-prod-4fbtvz3dva-ew.a.run.app). Locally I installed Prestashop with SSL disabled, then I needed to enable it manually on DB (hoping correctly).
- All extensions needed by Prestashop are installed
- LogLevel of Apache is "debug"

What can I do for resolve or troubleshoot the issue?

Thanks and best regards,
Alberto